# No such module 'FirebaseMessaging' in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoa

I'm trying to add Push Notifications to my iOS app in `Xcode` but getting the `No such module 'FirebaseMessaging'` error when I try to `import FirebaseMessaging` (FYI: import Firebase working just fine).

Running pod installs in Terminal shows that the `FirebaseMessaging` package was installed:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (10.5.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.5.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.5.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (10.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (10.5.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.2.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.11.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

**And, here's my pod file:**

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'AppName' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'

end
```

Any suggestions for how to fix this error?

I tried installing Firebase Messaging but it's not working in `Xcode`.

Comment: Were u able to resolve this